# Help with understanding this multiple choice question

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This question was asked in NBHM 2019. It has multiple correct answers.

Let $f$ be a continuous function from the real line $R$ to the closed interval [1,3] such that:

A) $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(3)$ are singletons and B) $f^{-1}(x)$ consists of exactly two real numbers for every $x$ in $(1,2)\cup (2,3)$. Which of the following can be the cardinality of $f^{-1}(2)$? Choose all the correct options:

a) 1 b) 2 c) countable infinity d) uncountable infinity.

I am  having trouble understanding this question. If $f^{-1}$ is to exist, then shouldn't it be that $f$ be bijective. Here B) suggests that $f$ could be many-one function. And $f^{-1}$ looks like one-many function, which can't be true. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: $f^{-1}(1)$ stands for the pre-image of $1$, it doesn't necessarily mean that $f$ is invertible.
Same for $f^{-1}(2)$ and $f^{-1}(3)$.

Comment: Can I assume that $f^{-1}$ is continuous as [1,3 ] is compact? So in that case a) and d) becomes correct?

Comment: To be more precise:
If $f:A \to B$ and $b\in B$, then $f^{-1}(b) = \{x \in A:f(x) = b\}$.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ isn't even well defined here, because in this case $f$ is not injective. This $f^{-1}$ in the problem has just the meaning I wrote above. Also, the problem assumes that $f$ is continous.

Comment: You can assume $f$ is continuous because it's stated that $f$ is continuous. It's not assumed to be injective. Example: $\sin^{-1}(0) = \{n \pi \,|\, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is countably infinite.

Comment: So a) is given as correct because there exists at least one pre image of $2$ and d) is given as correct because there can be uncountable infinite pre images. Is this reasoning correct?And thank you for answering!!

Comment: @NatashaJ In order to show that (a) is correct, you would need to show there's some $f$ such that $|f^{-1}(2)| = 1$. Instead, what you showed is that for all such $f$, $|f^{-1}(2)| \geq 1$. Those are not the same.

Comment: How can I show that cardinality of $f^{-1}(2)$ is $1$?